# Why are breakpoints green and not working?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I am trying to run a debug on my code, but somehow it stopped working. Here is a snippet and the green lines it is showing:

[image: snippet]

- I have tried to right click on my project and `clean` it.
- Tried
  to delete temporary files, like `.stat` and `.dcu`.
- Switching back and forth to `Release` and `Debug` modes, rebuilding, recompiling them.
- The `Debugging` options under `Project -> Options -> Delphi compiling`are all set to true.
- Checked if there are no duplicate files in the `search paths`.
- Other projects are working correctly.
- Also tried swearing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you do Build project after change settings?

Comment: And are you making a debug build?

Comment: Are there any other breakpoints working? If yes then the code you want to debug is not used in the application.

Comment: No, breakpoints are not working at all. Nowhere in the code. Yes, as I said, I tried to rebuild everything again in debug mode.

Comment: Well if swearing didn't help, I don't know what to say.

Comment: Maybe you have an host application set which does not suit your needs in *Run -> Parameters -> Debugger -> Host application*? Or *Run -> Attach to process* have to be set before start debugging?

Comment: @fantaghirocco good idea, but sadly no, it is empty.

Comment: Does it work if you place a breakpoint in the project main file on `Application.Initialize`?

Comment: Then it must be something in the project settings.

Comment: SO question: [why breakpoints from time to time are not usable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679989/delphi-why-breakpoints-from-time-to-time-are-not-usable-green-highlighted-line)

Comment: Try renaming the `.dproj` file to something else, for example adding an extension `.old` and then re-load your project. It will auto-generate a new one. Sure, you might lose a bunch of settings, but it seems the easiest solution.

Comment: We occasionally have this problem building using MSBuild rather than the old-school IDE compiler on XE8

Comment: Have have this issue on a regular basis. It exists since several Delphi version up to the latest. I never found a way to reproduce it easily. Nevertheless, to make it work again, I follow those steps: 1) Do a clean, 2) Stop the IDE, 3) Do a full build.

Comment: what about • The Debugging options under Project -> Options -> L:inking ? Do you build monolithic EXE or with BPLs? What can you see in View -> Debug windows -> modules ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a kind of normal compiler behaviour. It ever happens when the procedure (code line) is never called from anywhere inside your program. Compiler skips such procedures and functions (all the code lines within them). 
See the picture.

[image]

You just need to check if the procedure (line) is really at least once called from anywhere inside your application.

**Appended**

This also takes place when the code line can never be called and this (the logic statement) can be evaluated at compilation (the result is known in advance and can not be affected at runtime). The compiler optimizes the code skipping such lines. That is why it does not accept breaks at them.

[image]

Here is a diassembly of the latter procedure. The `if false then ...` statement at lines 37 and 38 is omitted:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer from asd-tm, I include the following line in all my units:

```
unit SomeRandomUnit;
{$I ProjOptions.inc}
```

In the ProjOptions.inc file, I include the following code:

```
// Compiler switches:
//              Debug Info      Optimisation
// DEBUG            On              Off
// RELEASE          Off             On
{$IFDEF DBG}
    {$D+}
    {$O-}
{$ELSE}
    {$D-}
    {$O+}
{$ENDIF}
```

In this way, optimisation is off and debug information switched on when I am debugging without me worrying about accidentally toggling something in Project > Options. Manually deleting DCU files from the PROJECT\objects folder (combined with the above .inc file) should guarantee breakpoints working again (at least in DEBUG builds).