# Break point works just once in library project

Tags: delphi-7

We have some library projects with a VPI extension. Defined in the DPR with library at start and {$E vpi} at end (Options > output settings > Application > Target file extension: vpi).

```pascal
library appname;
uses
  //...
{$E vpi}
```

Problem: When I run a debug in a VPI project it works only once. After any change it won't hit the break again. Now showing a "green" breakpoint when you run the app. The only way to get it back to work is by closing and open the IDE.

My Co-worker asked me if I have this problem last year, which I didn't. In his machine "when you change anything in your source, even a space in a comment, the break points won't work till you close and open the IDE again" he said.

We've compared lots of config from the IDE and we didn't find anything.

Now for some "no reason" my computer also stopped working with the debug.
I have looked into this topic "[Delphi: why breakpoints from time to time are not usable (green highlighted line on IDE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679989/delphi-why-breakpoints-from-time-to-time-are-not-usable-green-highlighted-line)" with no luck.

I've tried the Clear unit Cache, un-check and check again the debug info, include TD32, include remote debug, uncheck optimization.

I've asked to other teams and they said that some machines works others don't. But they also don't know why.

Maybe someone here have another trick that may help.

Comment: What is a "VPI project" and how does it relate to Delphi?

Comment: My bad with the naming, the {$E vpi} in the .DPR for a library. I think the normal is .dll. Have no ideia why they call vip.